# Realm Swift: Is it possible to keep database after the apps is uninstalled?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

Using realm swift, is it possible to keep and maintain the realm database file of the apps in device memory even after the apps is uninstalled from the device?

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Applications all files are leftover when deleting an app. iOS apps are Sandboxed. This means that each App has its own space in disk, with its own directories, which act as the home for the app and its data.

Deleting an app from the iPhone deletes this sandbox, deleting all data associated with the app.

Answer (score 8):

Sadly not. This is a limitation of iOS more than a limitation of Realm. When an iOS app is uninstalled from a device, all of the files associated with it are deleted (including any Realm files).

If you want file data to persist even after the app is deleted, you'll need to look at a cloud hosting solution to hang onto a copy of those files. In this case, the easiest one would most likely be [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/).

Comment: I agree with your answer but after quick read of [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/index.html) it says that data stored in <Application_Home>/Documents directory will automatically be backed up by iCloud. I'm pretty sure that's where default.realm is stored by default. Probably you know more about this? I've never worked with iCloud / CloudKit before

Comment: What that means is that the files in the Documents folder are included in your nightly iCloud backups for just that device. So if you want upgrade to a new iOS device (Or restore the old one), the file will come back down during the restoration. If you explicitly uninstall the app, that data is deleted from the device backup as well. It's a bit confusing, since it falls under Apple's umbrella term of 'iCloud', but is a different mechanism from CloudKit. :)

Comment: Unfortunately in my case the apps is an simple offline apps, so CloudKit is not right solution. As I googling, the possible solution is to implement backup and restore mechanism of the realm files manually to device's storage. So it needs to restore the database from the apps manually. Anyway thanks very much for your explanation @TiM, your answer are very helpful