# Troubleshooting iOS RealmSwift database restore from iCloud after app reinstall

Tags: ios, swift, realm, icloud

I have an app which uses realmSwift Database.

I'm trying to manually save the database to icloud which works fine so far Here is my code:

Backup:

```
let fileManager = FileManager.default
```

```
private func retrieveLocalRealmURL() -> URL {
        let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentaryDirectory = urls[0]
        let realmURL = documentaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent("default.realm");
        
        return realmURL
    }
    
    private func backupRealmToiCloudDrive() {
        let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        
        backgroundQueue.async {
            guard
                let ubiquityURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)
            else {
                return
            }
                
            let iCloudDriveURL = ubiquityURL.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
            let iCloudRealmURL = iCloudDriveURL.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
            
            let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudDriveURL.path, isDirectory: nil)
            
            func copy() {
                let localRealmURL = self.retrieveLocalRealmURL()
                
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: localRealmURL, to: iCloudRealmURL)
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sicherung erfolgreich", message: "Die Datenbank wurde erfolgreich in iCloud wiederhergestellt.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                    
                    print("Realm File succesfully uploaded to iCloud")
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
            
            if fileExists {
                self.deleteExistedFile(iCloudRealmURL)
                copy()
                print("File already existts, deleting old copy")
            } else {
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: iCloudDriveURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
                    copy()
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteExistedFile(_ url: URL) {
        let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
        
        fileCoordinator.coordinate(writingItemAt: url, options: .forDeleting, error: nil) { deleteURL in
            do {
                let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: deleteURL.path, isDirectory: nil)
                
                if fileExists {
                    try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: deleteURL)
                }
            } catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my code to restore from iCloud:

```
private func restoreRealmFromiCloudDrive() {
        let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        
        backgroundQueue.async {
            guard let ubiquityURL = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil) else {
                return
            }
            
            let iCloudDriveURL = ubiquityURL.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
            let iCloudRealmURL = iCloudDriveURL.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")
            
            let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: iCloudRealmURL.path, isDirectory: nil)
            
            if fileExists {
                let defaultRealmFileURL = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL
                let localRealmURL = self.retrieveLocalRealmURL()
                
                let fileCoordinator = NSFileCoordinator(filePresenter: nil)
                
                fileCoordinator.coordinate(writingItemAt: localRealmURL, options: .forReplacing, error: nil) { writeURL in
                    do {
                        print("Realm File exists on iCloud")
                        
                        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: defaultRealmFileURL!.path) {
                            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: defaultRealmFileURL!)
                        }
                        
                        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: iCloudRealmURL, to: defaultRealmFileURL!)
                        
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Restore Successful", message: "The restore from iCloud Drive was successful", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                        
                    } catch {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                        print("No Realm File on iCloud")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The file is succesfully written to iCloud, and I can also restore from there. However, when I delete the app and reinstall it, the restore function doesn't do anything anymore. Not even print statemenents are visible in the console. Can someone help me out with this?

Restore should also work after a reinstall of the app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Realm Swift: Is it possible to keep database after the apps is uninstalled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38342220/realm-swift-is-it-possible-to-keep-database-after-the-apps-is-uninstalled)

Comment: Did you do any troubleshooting? e.g. add a breakpoint in the `restoreRealmFromiCloudDrive` function, call it and then step through the code line by line until you spot something unexpected. Then include that info in the question. If the code is not being called at all, then the issue lies outside the code in the question and we won't be able to assist. Please update and clarify the question and we'll take a look.